# Vertical centering of single AND multiple line CSS with no fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have some text labels in html for example `<label>Short</label>` and `<label>This is a long label which is split into two line</label>`. These labels sit within a div element of varying heights. How can I center my text? I have used `display: table-cell; vertical-align: center;` which works for single line but not double lines, it pushes the double lined text outside of the `<div>` element.Any help?

Comment: FYI its `vertical-align: middle;` not `center`! A code snippet would be super helpful to show what is happening but did you want something like this: https://codepen.io/samwalker/pen/mmzMEd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it may work for you:

```
{ display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
```

Comment: tbh — Flexbox is the easiest solution & is supported by most modern browsers but IE9 and below doesn't support it at all! IE10 needs the 2012 style syntax & 11 can be tricky BUT if you're using autoprefixer life is easy.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I'd also argue that supporting the pre-IE 9 crowd isn't important at all. According to browser statistics, only 0.2% of IE users are on versions prior to IE 11 (W3Schools, source: https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). One could say this subsection is negligible, especially given that IE has its other quirks

Comment: @TCharb Your source is for visitors to W3Schools which is has developer heavy visitors and not representative of global usage at all. Depending on your audience, you can have far more IE visitors than that. My financial clients have up to 30% IE11 usage.

Comment: Hey @Rob - I had a feeling that what you're saying was correct after looking a bit closer. Just in a rush to sound smart, I guess ;) Do you have any quantitative insight on global usage? Edit: Saw your edit. That's significant!

Answer (score 0):

use `<center> <label> here is your label </label> </center>`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: You should not use the `<center>` tag. It was deprecated in HTML4.